# WPF bindings for settings read before execution

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, focus, exit

I have an application where bindings work almost as they should, there is just one problem:

Some GUI elements update the underlying data type "on exit" i.e. when focusing on something else. However, this doesn't happend when I click "execute" or "save" (saving settings). So if the last setting that was set was a textbox and the user didn't click somewhere else, the updated setting value is not included into the execution / setting save.

1. Is there a way to do this manually at execute/save?
2. Why doesn't my clicking on execute/save work as a focus change? Maybe it does but it doesn't happend until after the event for the button is run?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to explicitly update the binding for a specific textbox element or the focused textbox element in your execute/save method and still use LostFocus for the UpdateSourceTrigger property:

```
public static void UpdateBinding()
{
    UpdateBinding(Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox);
}

public static void UpdateBinding(TextBox element)
{
    if (element != null) 
    {
        var binding = element.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (binding != null) 
        {
            binding.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` on your textbox binding

**EDIT**

or use `UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"` and call the update method in your bindings when handling your button click

Comment: Sorry, can't do that, I do some validation with automatic actions that can not be done while the person is typing in the textbox. So I need a way of making all elements have their losefocus-events triggered.